# A Basic Javascript Question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Uploadify Plugin to upload images, the parameter response of the uploadify function will hold the value 1 if something goes wrong.

i did something like this and works perfectly fine.

```
if(response != 1) {
     $('#t_fileUploadName').append('<p>'+response+'<p/>');
     $("#t_fileUploadField").append("<input type='hidden' name='nstitle' value='" + response + "' />"); 
     $("#t_fileUploadBtn").remove();
      }
```

now i want to specify one more javascript condition, if the response is equal to one then it should print the following html  div

```
 <div id="dialog" title="Incorrect File Dimension" style=" display:none;">
            <p>Please enter the correct file dimension!</p>
        </div>
```

i tried using this code and it is not working.

```
if(response == 1) {
      $("#divmsg").append("<div id='dialog' title='Incorrect File Dimension' style=' display:none;'><p>Please Enter The Correct File Dimension, or Refer the Document</p></div>"); 
     }
```

what is wrong with the above syntax???

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not appending? The `style=' display:none;` in there will cause it not to show up, just something to check.

Comment: how do i make it to work? even i was thinking that semicolin  was creating the problem.

Comment: is there any way of escaping it?

Comment: Are you sure you're falling in the `if(response==1)` code block?  If you `alert(response)` right after it gets a value, what is the result?  And if you add an `alert('here!')` after `if(response==1){...`, does it fire?

Comment: yes it is if i give alert response it prints the value 1 and if i use the string it prints with here, it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code,But still If you can escape it

```
     $("#divmsg").append("<div id='dialog' title='Incorrect File Dimension' style=\"display:none;\"><p>Please Enter The Correct File Dimension, or Refer the Document</p></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `display:none`?

Comment: yes i got rid of it. it works . i am facing another problem now.

Comment: So the initial problem was the escaping or the display style?